# Reading android rlid socket

Tags: android, sockets, ussd

We are creating android application to control balance. we need to get data from android ussd socket "/dev/socket/rild" for root devices(only reading).

Algorithm of unix module (writen c/c++ ?):
- connect to rild socket
- connect to android application socket
- read data from rlid socket and write it into application socket

The module must read data by request. There is no need to read all data continuously.

Is it possible to use ip_tables?